# How can save to file the on screen output of a Python IDE?

Tags: python-2.7, logging, ide, anaconda, spyder

I use Spyder as my Python IDE. In most of what I do I use the editor to write code and execute portions of the program one at a time. I typically go back and forth, change things, add pieces, execute portions... you get it. Is there a way to save to file what Spyder shows in the console portion of the IDE after each portion of code is executed?

Comment: Why don't you write the output to a file?

Answer (score 5):

(*Spyder dev here*) Well, there is a way to save the output shown in our consoles but not after each execution. You have to do it manually, like this:

1. For our *Python* consoles, you need to do a right mouse click over any console and select the option *Save history log*.
2. For our *IPython* consoles, you need to do a right mouse click over any console and select the option *Save as HTML/XML*

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for an automated way to do it. Additionally, it seems like the method you suggested saves only the log that is physically visualized in the console. For long logs, that might only be the last part of the whole log.

Comment: Yeah, both methods I mentioned only save the visible part of the console. Take a look at [this link](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/2/interactive/reference.html#session-logging-and-restoring) to see how you can log an entire IPython session. I'm not sure if that saves both inputs and outputs, or just inputs, but it can be helpful :-)

Answer (score 0):

One way to capture entire console output of Sypder IDE:
1. Go to "Profile" (Shortcut: F10) under "Run" Tab.
2. On Right hand side, you can see Run, Stop and Output buttons.
3. Click on Run and the entire console session is captured under Output.

Hope, this helps. Kindly correct me if I am wrong.